# Is there a way for my users to be instantly logged in on a website with their computer/AD account?

Tags: laravel, oauth, active-directory

I'm building a Laravel website for the employees at the company I work at, but one of the requirements is that the users shouldn't have to fill in any credentials to log in, this means instant login when navigating to the website.

Right now I'm using an oauth package that lets them login with their Office365 email, they only have to use their email the first time they visit the website, but this isn't good enough to meet the requirements.

Does anyone know how to do this or a package I can use for this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you're in an exclusively windows enviroment, you can use the NTLM protocol with the help of this package: https://packagist.org/packages/jakub-klapka/laravel-windows-auth

But it comes with a few cavorts ...

- Only works with Windows.
- The site needs to be hosted using IIS on a windows server.
- The server must be on the same domain as the user.
- Works with Internet Explorer or Edge.  Supposedly you can do this with Chrome and FF but I haven't ever had success.

I haven't tried with Office365 and Azure AD but theoretically it could work. But again, I believe this is only possible if you're a 100% Microsoft shop. Personally, I'd say SSO through O365 is a much better long-term strategy. Support for NTLM seams to be waning, especially as things move into the cloud and IE/Edge continues to looses market share.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I've tried to install the package, but it won't install. Keep getting "Can only install one of : laravel/laravel[V*.*.*, No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) ].